# Basic auth header from username and password is not working In AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, basic-authentication

I am invoking A API its required Authorisation header.

this is API need on given URL

username : testingyouonit@gmail.com

password : testingyouonit2

to **create the Authorisation header**

step 1 - do a base64 encoding of the given password.

step 2 - do a SHA256 hash on the password obtained in step 1

step 3 - use the password obtained in step 2 and given username to create the authorization header

Now i am passing  request using AFNetworking

```
NSString *email=@"testingyouonit@gmail.com";
NSString *password=[self encodeStringTo64:@"testingyouonit2"];
```

Here i encoded my password

```
- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString
{
    NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String;
    if ([plainData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
        base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
    } else {
        base64String = [plainData base64Encoding];
    } 

    return base64String; 
}
```

Now i am passing GET Request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:email password:password];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"CAS256" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    [manager GET:@"https://myurlhere/youit" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Now each time i am getting this

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7c361610 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7aed9220> { URL: https://myurlhere/youit } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 114;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 11 Jul 2015 02:56:46 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.1.19";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myurlhere/youit, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f725f63 6f646522 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f61 7574685f 68656164 6572222c 0a202022 6d657373 61676522 3a202249 6e76616c 69642061 7574686f 72697a61 74696f6e 2e205573 6520616e 20617574 68206865 61646572 206f7220 61636365 73732068 61736822 0a7d>}
```

where is the mistake i am doing to make basic Auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets create SHA256 and pass it password and try it

```
NSString *email=@"testingyouonit@gmail.com";
NSString *password=[self encodeStringTo64:@"testingyouonit2"];
```

add one more method to generate a Sha256 password and pass in to request

Step-1 using this method you need to `#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

```
-(NSString*)sha256HashFor:(NSString*)input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and call this
Note : pass here encoded password you used

```
NSString *password=[self encodeStringTo64:@"testingyouonit2"];
 `password=[self sha256HashFor: password];`
```

and final step

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:email password:password];



    [manager GET:@"https://myurlhere/youit" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

let me see the result

Answer (score 0):

You aren't constructing the header correctly. See the "client side" section [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Incidentally, you are getting an error 400 which means your request is bad. If it was a security issue, you would be getting a 401. So, fix the Authorization header, but look further for the problem with your request.

Comment: Mike this i knew problem is client side but how to make Auth header here using my existing code where i need to change.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
NSString *URLString = @"url";


        NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

        NSString *authenticationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
        NSData *authenticationData = [authenticationString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authenticationValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
    [operation setCredential:credential];
    [operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];
    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using AFNetworking 3.x here is full solution that worked for me.
This code sends file with basic authentication. Just change url, email and password.

```
NSString *serverUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/uploadlink", profile.host];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:serverUrl parameters:nil error:nil];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

// Forming string with credentials 'myusername:mypassword'
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", email, emailPassword];
// Getting data from it
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Encoding data with base64 and converting back to NSString
NSString* authStrData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[authData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Forming Basic Authorization string Header
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authStrData];
// Assigning it to request
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[url path]];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
// This is not called back on the main queue.
// You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Update the progress view
                LLog(@"progres increase... %@ , fraction: %f", uploadProgress.debugDescription, uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
            });
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
            }
        }];
[uploadTask resume];
```